# Can someone explain the output of following code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hoisting

```js
var employeeId = 'abc123';
function foo() {
 employeeId = '123bcd';
 return;

 function employeeId() {
  var x = 0;
 }
}
foo();
console.log(employeeId); //abc123
```

---

The question is based on hoisting. We are printing employeeId in console.log here. Can someone explain the output of above code ?

Answer (score 3):

By the rule of hoisting, in the same closure, the `function` declaration is almost equivalent to:

```js
var employeeId = 'abc123';

function foo() {
 var employeeId = function () { // hoisted from the function below
  var x = 0;
 }

 employeeId = '123bcd';
 return;

 // function employeeId() {
 //  var x = 0;
 // }
}

foo();
console.log(employeeId); //abc123
```

So the outer scope `employeeId` hasn't been altered since it got obscured in the `foo` 
function scope.

Comment: Oh man this is so subtle. This problem is digging deep into Javascript's complications.